# Restrict ssh access to selected IP on macOS

Tags: terminal, ssh, network

I want to restrict ssh access on macOS 10.12 to selected IPs on my local network. I tried writing the following files:

```
# /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: 192.168.1.32
sshd: 192.168.1.33

# /etc/hosts.deny
sshd: ALL
```

Then restarting with:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Unloading `ssh.plist` successfully disabled ssh, but after reloading I can still connect from any IP.

How can I configure an IP whitelist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hosts.allow and hosts.deny are only used when you run the service (sshd) through TCP wrappers. The default macOS install does not do that, so they will not have any effect.

As recommended by other answers, you could use a firewall to restrict access to SSH. This could be a hardware (i.e. "external") firewall or a software firewall such as the built-in pf firewall.

However, I wouldn't recommend using a firewall only. The best is to limit the sshd service itself - and if you want, you can add the firewall protection to that. The reasoning behind that is that if for some reason your firewall gets disabled, outside users would suddenly be allowed access to communicate with sshd - you really do not want that.

In order to configure sshd to limit access, you will need to edit the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and add the following:

```
AllowUsers username@192.168.1.32 username@192.168.1.33
```

where you replace "username" with your actual username.

If you want you can replace parts with * to denote a wildcard, such as for example `username@192.168.1.*` or `*@192.168.1.32`. You can read more about the options in the man page for sshd_config.

Comment: I can't get past password authentification with this method. I am asked for my password 4 times then get the response `Received disconnect from [...] port 22:2: Too many authentication failures`

Comment: Did you want to login with a password? - What is your username? Please paste the actual line you've added to sshd_config?

Comment: I added `AllowUsers admin@192.168.1.32 admin@192.168.1.33` and then attempted to connect with `ssh admin@192.168.1.31`. Without the filter, I type my admin password to login successfully.

Comment: And the IP address of the PC you're trying to login from is what? - Can you confirm with the logs on the server that it is seeing the login from that IP? (in case you have multiple IPs) .. Have you restarted sshd after changing the configuration file?

Comment: Yes, I restarted sshd with launchctl. Here is what I see when I connect without any restrictions on IP: `sshd: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for admin from 192.168.1.32 port 38766 ssh2`

Comment: Fixed by replacing `admin` with `Admin`: `AllowUsers Admin@192.168.1.32 Admin@192.168.1.33`

Comment: Perfect, your real user name must be Admin then! :-)

Answer (score 2):

`hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` has been deprecated and you should be using a firewall (`pf`) instead.

The default rule for `pf` can be found in `/etc/pf.conf`.  You could edit this file directory or create your own custom rule set, but be sure to copy the contents of the default file to it.  Add the following two lines:

```
# The name of the network interface as shown in ifconfig
ext_if="en0"

tcp_services = "{ssh}"
icmp_types = "{echoreq, unreach}"
trusted = "{192.168.1.32, 192.168.1.33}"

# Exempt the loopback interface to prevent services that use if from being blocked
set skip on lo0

# This is a desktop so we have to be permissive in allowing outgoing  connections
pass out quick modulate state


# Block all incoming SSH Traffic by default 
  block in on $ext_if inet proto tcp from any to any port $tcp_services

# Allow SSH traffic from trusted IPs
pass in on $ext_if inet proto tcp from $trusted to any port $tcp_services
```

Next, enable `pf` with the command

```
$ sudo pfctl -e                                 #if using the default /etc/pf.conf
$ sudo pfctl -e -f /path/to/custom_pf.conf      #if using a custom pf.conf
```

This ruleset will by default, block SSH to all but the trusted IPs that are defined.  All other services will not be impacted.

Comment: I edited `/etc/pf.conf`, then enabled `pf` with `sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf`. Now I can't connect from my other machine: `ssh admin@192.168.1.31` hangs forever. Also this blocks all traffic, I can't connect to any website with `pf` enabled.

Comment: I've gone ahead and written a more comprehensive ruleset for a desktop setup.  See my edits.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the other answer which was simpler to implement.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. I'm able to ssh even after denying everything and not adding any trusted IP values.

Comment: @Husyn -  I’ve given two examples, *which* didn’t work? What did you try exactly?  If you can connect remotely from another host after blocking everything, `pf` isn’t running